# Accessing env values in page Javascript in Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

I cannot find how to achieve this. I am looking to access an `env` value in a page's javascript in Laravel 5.1. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried the following without success:

```
var AppImagePath = "<?php echo {!! env('APP_IMG_PATH') !!}?>";

var AppImagePath = {!! env('APP_IMG_PATH') !!};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var AppImagePath = '{!! env("APP_IMG_PATH") !!}';
    console.log(AppImagePath);
</script>
```

Using `<?php ?>` is unnecessary when you are printing values with blade brackets. And in the second one, you forgot the quotes.

Comment: Hi @manix, it does not work. I corrected your syntax as you where missing an apostrophe, but it still does not work. Console.log shows `{!! env("APP_IMG_PATH") !!}`

Comment: Look where I have put the `console.log` call. If the value is not printed, then you need to check if `APP_IMG_PATH` is setted at your server.

Comment: Also, remeber that the view should ends in `.blade.php` extension

Comment: Got it, brilliant, thanks! I was implementing directly in the js file, but putting it into the template worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will work perfectly fine
it work for me.

```
var AppImagePath ='{!!getenv('AppImagePath')!!}';<br><br> 

alert(AppImagePath);
```